# Missing hash prefix error when using tabbed controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a tabbed control in a page. I am getting the following error when I pass between tabs:

```
Error: [$location:ihshprfx] Invalid url "http://backoffice.localhost:3000/#tab_category", missing hash prefix "#!"
```

Tabs are still working, but browser logs error each time I change tabs.

What should I do in order to avoid those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not already, use Angular Bootstrap, here are the instructions for the [tab controller](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs).  Using the the tabset directive you will not have to split the tabbar from its contents and the directive handles showing and hiding the tab panels.